# Rotate (alignment) an image by line along the y-axis

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to rotate (alignment) an image, which contain line (with two points `P1` and `P2`) along the `y-axis`

#### Original image:

[image]

*Note: the green area represents the original image*

#### Result should be:

[image]

*Note: the red area represents the original image after rotation*

So I need to calculate the angle between line defined by `P1(x1,y1)` and `P2(x2,y2)` and by `y-axis`,

[image]

*Note: the green line represents the y-axis*

My code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import *
import math
import imutils

height = 500
width = 500

original_image = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
original_image[:] = (0,255,0)

x1 = 400
y1 = 50

P1 = (x1, y1)

x2 = 100
y2 = 300

P2 = (x2, y2)

cv2.line(original_image, P1, P2, (0, 0, 0), 3)

deltaY = y1 - y2
deltaX = x1 - x2

angleInDegrees = atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / math.pi

print(angleInDegrees)

rotated_image = imutils.rotate_bound(original_image, angleInDegrees)

cv2.imshow("Original", original_image)
cv2.imshow("Rotated", rotated_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But my rotated_image is not properly aligned

Result looks like:

[image]

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you are calculating the wrong angle. The angle you are calcuating is between a vector originating at the origin and ending at P1 & a vector orignating at the origin and ending at P2.

The angle you need is between the vector starting at P1 and ending at P2 `[P2-P1]` & a vector that represents the direction of the y-axis which would be `[0, 1]`.

Secondly you have to take into account that your origin is in the top left corner so you need to reflect the angle once calculated.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import *
import math
import imutils


height = 500
width  = 500

original_image = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
original_image[:] = (0,255,0)

x1 = 400 
y1 = 50

P1 = np.array([x1, y1])

x2 = 100
y2 = 300

P2 = np.array([x2, y2])

# checks orientation of p vector & selects appropriate y_axis_vector
if (P2[1] - P1[1]) < 0:
    y_axis_vector = np.array([0, -1])
else:
    y_axis_vector = np.array([0, 1])

if (P2[0] - P1[0]) < 0 and (P2[1] - P1[1]) :
    y_axis_vector = np.array([0, 1])

p_unit_vector = (P2 - P1) / np.linalg.norm(P2-P1)
angle_p_y     = np.arccos(np.dot(p_unit_vector, y_axis_vector)) * 180 /math.pi

cv2.line(original_image, tuple(P1), tuple(P2), (0, 0, 0), 3)


print(angle_p_y)
print (P2-P1)


rotated_image = imutils.rotate_bound(original_image, -angle_p_y)

cv2.imshow("Original", original_image)
cv2.imshow("Rotated", rotated_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: remember to click the tick if you accept the answer :)

Comment: Yes, I don't forget that ... but .. what if values are: `height = 640`, `width = 480` and `x1 = 136`, `y1 = 581`, `x2 = 313` and `y2 = 138`

Comment: try it & find out

Comment: Result will be: https://pasteboard.co/J5Av5Oy.jpg and this is wrong, or no ?

Comment: OOps yeah my bad the `y_axis_vector` should be `[0, -1]` will edit answer, soz

Comment: Very good, and may I ask something? Is there any "universal" solution if line will be contrariwise? E.g. `height = 480`, `width = 640`, `x1 = 581`, `y1 = 424`, `x2 = 175`, `y2 = 109`. Thank you! That is my "last" problem

Comment: Yes you can check the orientation of `p` & select the appropriate `y_axis_vector` have edited answer to give a "universal" solution

Comment: Can I ask you something else after all? Is there any method to get the new positions of points `P1_r(x1_new, y1_new)` and `P2_r(x2_new, y2_new)` after rotation?